# Echo Most Recent Sticky Post in Loop?

Tags: loop, homepage, the-content

I am looking to echo the most recent post in the loop of content. Only 1 post.

Do I need to put some sort of parameter on the following code:

```
if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : 
    the_post(); 

        the_content(); 

    endwhile; 
endif;
```

How could I do this?

Comment: That's waay too much inline code - where is this? Did you try turning while to an if?

Comment: This is on one of my page templates. I don't necessarily need to use this code - just echo the most recent post in the loop (only 1).

Answer (score 0):

If it's your main loop, you could add this to your `function.php`:

```
function custom_pre_get_posts($query) {
    if($query->is_main_query() && /* is sticky conditional tag(sorry I need to check what is that) */) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', "1");
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts');
```

Or you can make a new WP_Query instance in the theme file:

```
<?php 
$onePost = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => // your post type,
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts')
));
if($onePost->have_posts()) :
    while(($onePost->have_posts()) :
        $onePost->the_post(); 
?>
// your post HTML as normal
<?php 
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    endif; 
?>
```

Please note that if you use the WP_Query then you need to set all parameters you need to custom the post. You could read this in the WP_Query Codex

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```
function latest_sticky() { 

    /* Get all sticky posts */
    $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

    /* Sort the stickies with the newest ones at the top */
    rsort( $sticky );

    /* Get the latest */
    $sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 1 ); //Change the 1 to get more than one.

    /* Query sticky posts */
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 ) );
    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $return .= '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $return .= '<li><a href="' .get_permalink(). '" title="'  . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a><br />' . get_the_excerpt(). '</li>';

        }
        $return .= '</ul>';

    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $return; 

}
```

Just do a `<?php echo latest_sticky();?>` anywhere your templates.